# delayer the one xml files to multiple xml files and add the attribute in the section element on the basis of section level

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

We want to break an xml file according to `section/@id` and also create a folder according to `section/@id` level, in that folder there will be xml files.
And as soon as we break the xml file, we will add an attribute in that xml files and those who add these attributes will add them according to the section level.

**1st scenario :** `If section level is more than 5th or 5th level then we will add attribute in 4th and 5th level of section and will not add in other section level (eg 3rd and 2nd level section )`

**Second Scenario :** `If section level is up to 4th only then we will add attribute only in 4th & 3rd section level`

**3rd Scenario:** `If section level is upto 3rd only then we will add attribute only in 3rd & 2nd section level`

**4th scenario:** `If section level is up to 2nd only then we will add attribute only in 2nd section level`

**Note:** `I am able to delayer the xml files into xml files but unable to add the attribute as per section level condition, Please look my expected result`

Sorry for more inputs, Please help me

**First Scenario Input**

```
<section id="asd_1">
    <sect>
        <title>Title here</title>
    </sect>
    <p>text here</p>
    <section id="tier">
        <sect>
            <title>Title here</title>
        </sect>
        <p>text here</p>
        <section id="dert">
            <sect>
                <title>Title here</title>
            </sect>
            <p>text here</p>
            <section id="tier">
                <sect>
                    <title>Title here</title>
                </sect>
                <p>text here</p>
                <section id="ert">
                    <sect>
                        <title>Title here</title>
                    </sect>
                    <p>text here</p>
                    <section id="bntur">
                        <sect>
                            <title>Title here</title>
                        </sect>
                        <p>text here</p>
                        <section id="rtfg">
                            <sect>
                                <title>Title here</title>
                            </sect>
                            <p>text here</p>
                            <section id="kuytreb">
                                <sect>
                                    <title>Title here</title>
                                </sect>
                                <p>text here</p>
                            </section>
                        </section>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

**2nd scenario Input**

```
<section id="wqat">
    <sect>
        <title>Title here</title>
    </sect>
    <p>text here</p>
    <section id="tewt">
        <sect>
            <title>Title here</title>
        </sect>
        <p>text here</p>
        <section id="weqs">
            <sect>
                <title>Title here</title>
            </sect>
            <p>text here</p>
            <section id="awrt">
                <sect>
                    <title>Title here</title>
                </sect>
                <p>text here</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

**3rd Scenario Input**

```
<section id="werd">
    <sect>
        <title>Title here</title>
    </sect>
    <p>text here</p>
    <section id="vbty">
        <sect>
            <title>Title here</title>
        </sect>
        <p>text here</p>
        <section id="gtyuioplkj">
            <sect>
                <title>Title here</title>
            </sect>
            <p>text here</p>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

**4th Scenario Input:**

```
<section id="fred">
    <sect>
        <title>Title here</title>
    </sect>
    <p>text here</p>
    <section id="bgtf">
        <sect>
            <title>Title here</title>
        </sect>
        <p>text here</p>
    </section>
</section>
```

**My XSL Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="section[@id]">
        <xsl:result-document href="{@id}/{@id}.xml" method="xml" encoding="utf-8">
        <section>
            <xsl:if test="@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </section>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <title>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected output**

```
<section id="ert" myatt="section_5th">
        <sect>
            <title>Title here</title>
        </sect>
    </section>
```

Comment: If I understand your description then it sounds as if you want to match on e.g. `section/section/section/section/section`, `section/section/section/section`, `section/section/section` .... Or check the `count(ancestor-or-self::section)` and adapt your code/emit the attribute based on that.

Comment: Yes, Martin Can you suggest me how to achieve the expected output for that scenarios

Comment: there are more xml files as per above scenario, some xml files have more then five section level and some xml files have less then five section but we will add the attribute as per section level

Comment: You have shown four different inputs but only one expected output; are all input samples supposed to generate that same output?

Comment: Yes Martin, we want same output as per expected output

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters have mentioned, it's very difficult to understand your requirement from either your description or your inputs/output.

In the interest of perhaps getting you closer, I'm going to propose a simple de-layering of the section elements.

You've discovered how to use `xsl:result-document` to produce multiple output documents from XSLT; hence, your problem now is how to break up and construct the different `section` elements that will make up each of your separate documents.

Your one example output shows an additional attribute `myatt` in the section element which contains the level number; the below suggestion constructs this attribute in a simple fashion.

Your xslt proposal has

```
<xsl:result-document href="{@id}/{@id}.xml" ...>
```

but this is not guaranteed to be unique as you can have the same id for more than section.  I'm proposing instead that you guarantee uniqueness by using the "level" added to the URL of the output.

Also, you mention other XML documents under the directory but give no examples of this, hence it's difficult to understand the requirement.

So, for what it's worth, here is an example that may help you get closer.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:l="local:functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd l"
    version="2.0">
  
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  
    <xsl:template match="/" >
      <sections>
        <xsl:for-each select="//section[@id]">
          <xsl:result-document href="{@id}-{l:level(.)}/{@id}.xml" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </sections>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[@id]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:attribute name="myatt" select="concat('section_', l:level(.))" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="* except section" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:function name="l:level" as="xs:integer" >
      <xsl:param name="thisSection" as="element(section)" />
      
      <xsl:sequence select="count($thisSection/ancestor-or-self::section)" />
    </xsl:function>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces a number of result documents, given your first scenario input.

document: **asd_1-1/asd_1.xml**

```
<section id="asd_1" myatt="section_1">
   <sect>
      <title>Title here</title>
   </sect>
   <p>text here</p>
</section>
```

document: **tier-2/tier.xml**

```
<section id="tier" myatt="section_2">
   <sect>
      <title>Title here</title>
   </sect>
   <p>text here</p>
</section>
```

document: **dert-3/dert.xml**

```
<section id="dert" myatt="section_3">
   <sect>
      <title>Title here</title>
   </sect>
   <p>text here</p>
</section>
```

document: **tier-4/tier.xml**

```
<section id="tier" myatt="section_4">
   <sect>
      <title>Title here</title>
   </sect>
   <p>text here</p>
</section>
```

Note that this is the reason for adding the `level` count to the output folder name because, otherwise, you would try to write two documents with the output URL for "tier/tier.xml": one for the level 2 and one for the level 4 sections, both with the `id` attribute **tier**.

There are 4 more section document outputs produced for that input file.

Hoping this helps and good luck.